# Intentional no-op in object instance of large interface

Tags: android, kotlin

Lets say there was a large interface for a listener:

```
interface Listener {
   fun onEvent1();
   fun onEvent2();
   ....
}
```

When we want to pass an instance of this listener, we'd write:

```
addListener(object: Listener { 
    override fun onEvent1() { }
    override fun onEvent2() { }
    etc...
})
```

However, if I only wanted to subscribe to 1 particular event, lets say `onEvent12()`, I'd still have to override all of the rest of the declared functions in the interface, which fills the code with empty function bodies. Is there a Kotlin idiomatic way to state that the rest of them can just be empty functions (no-ops), and I only want to override specific functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Kotlin, [interfaces](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/interfaces.html) can have default method implementations, so just define them as no-ops:

```
interface Listener {
  fun onEvent1() { }
  fun onEvent2() { }
  ....
}
```

Then just override only the one you care about:

```
addListener(object: Listener { 
  override fun onEvent1() { /* this is the one I care aboue */ }
})
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 3):

That does not really make sense. When you implement an interface you have to stick to the *full* contract since clients most probably will use references of this interface without knowing the concrete implementation. Your approach would kinda destroy the purpose of interfaces, don’t you agree?

As you stated your requirements, it would make sense to split the interface in multiple ones, e.g. per event. A concrete class can then implement 0..n of these listener interfaces.

Comment: Thats a good point, the proper way to implement multiple listeners should have an abstract concrete implementation class with all no-ops, of which you can override whichever events you want.

Answer (score 0):

While there are good reasons not to provide it in the language, as @s1m0nw1 says, it can actually be done using [Java reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html):

```
val handler: InvocationHandler = { _, method, _ ->
    when (method.name) {
        "onEvent12" -> // your implementation here
        else -> {} // do nothing
    }
}
val listener = Proxy.newProxyInstance(
    Listener::class.java.classLoader,
    arrayOf(Listener::class.java),
    handler) as Listener
```

This isn't something you should normally be doing and you should expect significant performance overhead! But it can still be useful if you have no other choice, e.g. if the listener interface is itself determined dynamically.